# Enquiry about Unit Test Concept in .NET Custom Environment

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, dll

I have an environment that would consume my custom DLL.

So, what I do are:

> 1. Create C# class library project in Visual Studio.
> 2. Add references of Environment DLLs to my class library project.
> 3. I call certain function or API from the Environment DLLs in my class library project.
> 4. I build my class library project and deploy it into the environment.
> 5. Setup the environment to call my DLL.
> 6. If I am required to debug my custom DLL, I need to attach process to my environment process.

All are good in development and debugging. But, I am not sure about the unit testing.

How to do the unit testing of my custom DLL since my custom DLL is really dependable with the environment DLL?

Is there any Unit Testing Library that I could use to perform Unit test similar like NUnit?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question. How this is different to any other development? What do you mean with "Environment DLLs"?

Comment: Your question can't really be answered in it's current form.   There are various techniques that could be used to decouple your C# classes from it's dependencies in the Environment DLL (such as dependency injection), which allow you to use mocks/stubs to isolate the dependency, however without more information about the nature of the dependency, your code + how you use the environment dll it's difficulty to suggest the correct way forward.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Ok, so basically, the environment is referring to application running in Java Runtime. The Environment DLLs are .NET DLL that serves as API adapter to communicate with the environment.

Comment: My custom DLL is running by action triggered in the environment. So, my Custom DLL is really dependent with the Environment.

Comment: Now, I am really wondering how to develop unit test codes for my custom DLL when my codes are really only be able to be executed by action triggered in the environment.